# Why can't modify value in object? Also How can I Improve on this Linked List?

Tags: c++, list

I'm fairly new to C++ as I come from java and python. Here is my attempt at linked list. I tried to initialise the Node with data but it didn't work rather in the append function I had to pass in the data for it to show up. How can I improve this, before making sure that the last node pointed to null I had a memory error exc bad access why is that.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int data){
        this->data = data;
    }
};

class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* head;

public:
    void showList(){
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL){
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
            if (temp->next == NULL){
                cout << temp->data << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    void append(int data) {
        Node* nodeToAdd = new Node(data);
        nodeToAdd->data = data;
        nodeToAdd->next = NULL;

        Node* temp = head;
        if (head->next == NULL){
            head->next = nodeToAdd;

            return;
        }
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = nodeToAdd;
    }

    LinkedList(){
        head->next = NULL;
        cout << "Linked list created" << endl;
    }
};

int random(int upto){
    int random = rand() % 100+1;
    return random;
}

int main() {
    LinkedList theLink;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        theLink.append(i);
    }
    theLink.showList();
    cout << "Finished" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear what didn't work?

Comment: Be consistent in your code style, use `this->` when accessing all members, don't limit to only constructor.

Comment: No reason to improve; the C++ language has `std::list`, use that in future projects.

Comment: @StephenNewell when I Intialize nodeToADd with data it does not work rather I had to do nodeToAdd ->data = data

Comment: Unrelated: When you proceed to later rounds of testing don't forget to call `srand` to seed the random number generator. If you don't seed the RNG, the program will run with the default seed which will always be the same and always generate the same sequence of numbers. Always generating the same sequence is handy while testing to make it easier to see if a change you made really did make a change.

Comment: Also unrelated: `rand` is usually a pretty bad random number generator. It worked well in the constraints that spawned it, computers with next to no memory and CPUs clocked in kHzs, but these days you should prefer to use the [tools in the `<random>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed / has undefined behavior because you dereference `head` (e.g. with `if (head->next == NULL)`...), although the pointer `head` is never initialized.

Your `append` should check if `head` is already set to a value before traversing through all the `head->next` elements. Adapt the show list accordingly, too.

```
class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* head = nullptr;

public:
    void append(int data) {
        Node* nodeToAdd = new Node(data);

        if (head == nullptr) {
           head = nodeToAdd;
        }
        else {
           Node* temp = head;
           while (temp->next != NULL) {
             temp = temp->next;
           }
        ...
```

also, similarly with Node::next so after appending the first node it will fail. So,

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense I did get an error where the while loop didnt break and was infinite and I think it was because of this and I made sure the new node had null next pointer in the append function. This is a much better way thank you